# crons stopping for no reason

Tags: php, cron

Well this isn't true, I'm sure there's a reason, but I can't find it!!

I have a script that can take around 10 minutes to execute. It does a lot of communicating with an api on a service that we have that use. It pulls a bit of a fingerprint of everything every 24 hours. So what it's doing is pretty aside from the point. the probm I'm finding is the script stops executing somewhat randomly!!

I can't find any errors that would cause my script to stop executing, even with

```
//for debugging
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

on for debugging, it's all clean. I've also used

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

so that it shouldn't ever time out.

With that said, I'm not sure how to get any more debug info to figure out what it's stopping. I can say that the script should NOT be hitting any memory limits or anything. I mean that should throw an error, and I've gone through and cleaned this script up as much as I can see to clean it up.

So my Question is: What are common causes for a cron ending when it shouldn't? How can I debug this more effectively?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a [register_shutdown_function()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) to define a codeblock that will execute when the script shuts down. Then create a variable across the main code execution points in the cron with details of what is going on. In the shutdown function write this into a log and check your log to see what state the program was in when it stopped. Of course, this is based on the assumption that your code is not totally erroring out.

You could also redirect the standard echo statements and logs into a log file by using

```
/path/to/cron.php > /path/to/log.txt 2>&1
```

`2>&1` indicates that the standard error `(2>)` is redirected to the same file descriptor that is pointed by standard output `(&1)`.So, both standard output and error will be redirected to `/path/to/log.txt`

UPDATE:

Below is a function/flow that I usually use in my crons:

```
function addLog($msg)
{
    if(empty($msg)) return;
    $handle   = fopen('log.txt', 'a');
    $msg = $msg."\r\n";
    fwrite($handle,$msg);
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Then I use it like so:

```
addLog("Initializing...");
init();
addLog("Finished initializing...");
addLog("Calling blah-blah API...");
$result = callBlahBlah();
addLog("blah-blah API returned value". $result);
```

It is more tedious to have all these logs, but when cron messes up, it really helps!

For eg. when you look at your log.txt and if you see something like:

```
Initializing...
Finished initializing...
Calling blah-blah API...
```

And there is no entry which says `blah-blah API returned value`, then you know that the function call to blah-blah messed up.

Comment: This is a pretty awesome approach that I hadn't considered with the shut down function. I'm not sure that it'll really debug things perfectly, but it'll give me a bit more insight into diagnosing things.On the log file, I've got it spitting into a log file already with the exact method you described. It gets about 2/3 through everything then it just seems to stop, and I can't find a reason for it. i've debugged to the point that I can rule out memory errors or most other things that you'd assume to stop a script. it's not outputting anything helpful, it just seems to stop mid execution!!

Comment: Well, its a good start that you can at least figure out until where the execution is going. Is your logging mechanism comprehensive enough that you can see which codeblock/function execution is causing the breakage? I would recommend you to add some additional/detailed logging there so that the output is actually helping you to debug better...

Comment: Right now it's just showing whatever I echo. This is the first time I've ever needed to use a cron to let me code execute so I'm still finding out the differences from running it in a browser window, lol. I had to do a few tests to even make sure certain things even worked at all. it's still odd, as if it was timing out, i'm just not finding out how to add any error messages to indicate that.

Comment: @JohnSly - I am going to update my answer with a simple logging function/flow that I have used over the years... I write and maintain a lot of crons and it is has helped me a lot in the past, hope it helps you too!

Answer (score 1):

> What are common causes for a cron ending when it shouldn't?

The most common in my experience is that the cron user has different permissions or different environment variables than the way that you're executing it from the command line.

Make your cronned program dump its environment to a temporary file and see if it's what you expect.

Comment: I'm googling it, but is there a quick simple way to get it to dump those out that you add to your answer? I'm going to try this, but it gets far enough in that I'm not for sure this would cause the error.

Comment: You're in PHP, so just run `phpinfo()`.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php  You can pass the `INFO_ENVIRONMENT` to limit the output to just the environment.

Comment: I'm starting to believe that the problem is my server terminating it.